# Why can’t I type during git clone PuTTY connection?

Tags: windows, ssh, git, putty

I want to clone git repo from CLI in Windows. When I'm executing:

```
git clone '...'
```

I am then getting:

```
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:                       
ssh-rsa blablabla
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to         
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.                      
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without       
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".                     
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the  
connection.                                                 
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

When I'm trying to type anything, then there is no reaction. When I'm terminating with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then all the typing queue is executed with 'yyyyyyyy' or other previous input.

What could be a problem here?

Comment: Fix can be running "putty.exe -ssh user@host"- it runs a putty gui, where accepting key adding is through a button (and then running git clone, with key saved), but it could be nice to know, why this is not working in cli...

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Krysian's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1252276/cant-type-during-git-clone-putty-connection#comment1839394_1252276) suggests, you can use PuTTY's GUI directly.

You just need to fill the “Hostname” with your target server address and press “Open.”

[image]